# Error in .jcall()

Tags: r

I am running the following code and receiving this error:

> Error in .jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer,
>   :    java.lang.NullPointerException

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\jbarr\\Desktop\\test)
library (tm); library (wordcloud);library (RWeka); library (tau);library(xlsx);

Comment <- read.csv("testfile.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
str(Comment) 
review_source <- VectorSource(Comment) 

corpus <- Corpus(review_source)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords,stopwords(kind = "english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c("member", "advise", "inform", "informed", "caller", "call","provided", "advised")) 


dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm2 <- as.matrix(dtm)
wordfreq <- colSums(dtm2)
wordfreq <- sort(wordfreq, decreasing=TRUE)
head(wordfreq, n=100)
wfreq <- head(wordfreq, 500)
set.seed(142)
words <- names(wfreq)
dark2 <- brewer.pal(6, "Dark2")
wordcloud(words[1:100], wordfreq[1:100], rot.per=0.35, scale=c(2.7, .4), colors=dark2, random.order=FALSE)
write.xlsx(wfreq, "C:\\Users\\jbarr\\Desktop\\test")
```

The interesting problem is, I have ran this code on multiple files, and only specific ones have the error.

Answer (score 1):

Sanmeet is right - it's a problem with `NAs` in your data frame.

just prior to your line: `review_source <- VectorSource(Comment)`

insert the line below:

```
Comment[which(is.na(Comment))] <- "NULLVALUEENTERED"
```

This will change all of your `NA` values to the phrase `NULLVALUEENTERED` (feel free to change that). No more `NAs`, and the code should run fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error in tokenizer due to NA in your string vector `Comment`

```
Comment <- read.csv("testfile.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
str(Comment)     
length(Comment)
Comment = Comment[complete.cases(Comment)]
length(Comment)
```

Or you can also use is.na as below

```
Comment = Comment[!is.na(Comment)]
```

Now apply the preprocessing steps, create the corpus etc

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are `NAs` in your data Frame. Run `is.na()` and remove those rows. Try running the code again. It should work.

Comment: @MartinEvans But the logic is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A Suggestion: I get this error when reading an excel (.xlsx) file using:

```
df2 <- read.xlsx2("foobar.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1", startRow = 1, endRow = 0).
```

Notice it appears that the value for endRow should be NULL or a valid number. But

```
df2 <- read.xlsx2("foobar.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")
```

works fine. So you might want to check your argument values and argument to parameter alignment.