# R text mining: error in extracting bigrams from corpus during tokenization step

Tags: java, r

Fetching data from url:

```
suppressMessages(library(readr))
suppressMessages(library(RCurl))


amazon_url <- getURL('http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_935/datasets/500_amzn.csv',
      ssl.verifyhost=FALSE, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
amazon <- read.csv(textConnection(amazon_url), header = TRUE)
```

Create `amzn_cons`:

```
amazon_cons <- amazon$cons
```

Build cleaning function based `qdap` package for text organization:

```
suppressWarnings(library(qdap))
qdap_clean <- function(x) {
x <- replace_abbreviation(x)
x <- replace_contraction(x)
x <- replace_number(x)
x <- replace_ordinal(x)
x <- replace_symbol(x)
x <- tolower(x)
return(x)
}
```

Build cleaning function based on `tm` package for text organization:

```
suppressWarnings(library(tm))
tm_clean <- function(corpus) {
      corpus<- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords,
      c(stopwords("en"), "Amazon","company"))
      return(corpus)
}
```

Word cleaning:

```
amzn_cons <- qdap_clean(amazon_cons)
amzn_cons <- VCorpus(VectorSource(amzn_cons))
amzn_cons_corp <- tm_clean(amzn_cons)
```

Build custom function to extract bigram features:

```
    suppressWarnings(library(RWeka))
    tokenizer <- function(x) 
    NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
```

Apply tokenization function to get bigrams words:

```
  amzn_c_tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(
  amzn_cons_corp,control = list(tokenize = tokenizer) )
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error in .jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer,  : 
  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: I have edited your question for clarity and formatting. Please see that no essential information is lost.

Comment: Tks, really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Huang This question [appeared already](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33744495/1655567) on quite a few occasions, it seems that the problem may be concerned with the Java installation, I would suggest that you consider following [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35179151/1655567) to ensure that your Java configuration is fit for purpose.

Comment: if you are using a linux machine, try doing $sudo R CMD javareconf, if you see an error then there are issues with your java installation

Comment: 10.
stop(structure(list(message = "java.lang.NullPointerException", call = .jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer, "weka/core/tokenizers/Tokenizer"), .jarray(as.character(control)), .jarray(as.character(x))), jobj = <S4 object of class structure("jobjRef", package = "rJava")>), .Names = c("message", ...
9.
.jcheck()
8.
.jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer, "weka/core/tokenizers/Tokenizer"), .jarray(as.character(control)), .jarray(as.character(x)))
7.
NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3))
6.
.tokenize(doc)   @Dinesh.hmn

Comment: could i know the possible detail issue about the java installation ?                               above is the error traceback code